# How to include £ pound symbol in email subject line in java mail

Tags: java, encoding, jakarta-mail

How can I include a pound symbol in the subject line of an email sent via java mail?

It shows incorrectly when I sent it.

Comment: Set the message charset as UTF-8.

Comment: @Gentleman: it's a problem of *header* encoding, not content encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subject is a header. Headers use only ascii-7 so to encode none ascii-7 chars properly you should use proper encoding.

If the class you're using lets you indicate some encoding try with UTF-8.

```
mimeMessage.setSubject(yourSubject, "UTF-8");
```

If you're writing the headers by hand use any of this:

```
MimeUtility.encodeWord(yourSubject, "UTF-8", "B"); // base-64
MimeUtility.encodeWord(yourSubject, "UTF-8", "Q"); // quoted-printable
```

That's more or less what MimeMessage does in setSubject(str, encoding):

```
setHeader("Subject", MimeUtility.fold(9, MimeUtility.encodeText(subject, charset, null)));
// fold splits the value in several lines with no more than 72 chars
```

**Sample**

I've tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // manual encoding
        System.out.println(MimeUtility.encodeText("How to include £ pound symbol", "UTF-8", "Q"));
        System.out.println(MimeUtility.encodeText("How to include £ pound symbol", "UTF-8", "B"));

            // MimeMessage encoding
        MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage((Session) null);
        m.setSubject("How to include £ pound symbol", "UTF-8");
        m.setContent("lalala", "text/plain");
        m.writeTo(System.out);
    }
```

and the output was:

```
=?UTF-8?Q?How_to_include_=C2=A3_pound_symbol?=
=?UTF-8?B?SG93IHRvIGluY2x1ZGUgwqMgcG91bmQgc3ltYm9s?=
```

(...)

```
Message-ID: <21944831.01314352473121.JavaMail.HAC001ES@SE115179>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?How_to_include_=C2=A3_pound_symbol?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

lalala
```

Anyway you could always use:

```
String yourEncodedString = MimeUtility.encodeText(str, "UTF-8", "Q");
mimeMessage.setHeader("Subject", yourEncodedString);
```

Comment: I have tried the first snippet after a google before asking this question, and does not work for me. I am not writing the headers.

Comment: Try to do `mimeMessage.writeTo(System.out);` so we can see how is encoding your subject (using the `setSubject(str, "UTF-8")` proposal). I'm curious...

Comment: Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?test_-_only_=EF=BF=BD3.99?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=Cp1252
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Comment: The problem is `EF BF BD` is not the byte representation in UTF-8 of the pound symbol. Try to pass the pound symbol in a literal string (as I've done) and you should obtain two bytes: `C2 A3`. Where are you extracting the string from? Maybe a properties file? If it's the case you should take care of its own encoding too!

Comment: @helios, `EF BF BD` is the UTF-8 encoding of 0xFFFD which is used to replace an illegal UTF-8 sequence. So, it looks like whatever the OP is reading the symbol from is not valid a UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: It could be because the String for the subject is retrieved from a HTML form in a JSP.

Comment: Definitively. Then make the encoding of the form element the same as the encoding that the server reads. If the form uses GEt, it puts the data into the URL, and then it cannot say "it's encoded at UTF-8"... you should configure your server to accept UTF-8 encoded URI's and configure the FORM element to send it that way (don't remember now). Or use POST... :)

Comment: Let's say your server accepts reads URIs encoded in ISO-8859-1 (default for Tomcat I think, it's configured on server.xml). Then you must tell the browser `<FORM accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">` to encode special chars correctly. If you don't tell it, it will use page encoding (UTF-8 I guess). But of course I recommend using UTF-8 in all places, so you will have to indicate it in <FORM...> (never trust default browser behaviour!) and configure the server.

Comment: One more recommendation: when you have a multi-step transformation problem, try to verify on which step the thing broke. In this case you should make a log or System.println of the literal string on the server, so you can check it's on or not BEFORE sending the email.

Comment: I would say that the problem doesnt exist in obtaining the data from the form. If i put String subject_p = request.getParameter("subject"); System.out.println(subject_p); it would return correctly

Comment: Nope. sorry. I have had a debugging session and the string is saved to a file after being grabbed from a form, then read from the file. and the value is saved correctly when viewing the file, so the problem must be related to the file read. Sorry for the long discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Set your encoding to UTF-8..

```
msg.setContent(message,"text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: That indicates the encoding for the body of that mime-part (the main content) but it doesn't relates to the headers encoding (where the subject is). I'm not sure that the implementation of Message use this encoding also for correctly encoding the headers (specially if they need their own weird encoding)

Comment: Will this affect the subject line?